# Servlet Not Reachable

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I am submitting a form via Javascript as `document.videoReleaseForm.submit();`

and the form definition is : `<form name="videoReleaseForm" id="videoReleaseForm" action="studController">`

When the control reaches the javascript code and tries to submit it to the servlet, I get the message as : `You don't have permission to access /student/studController on this server.`

What might be the issue here.

Comment: Unlikely it is the JavaScript. Can you submit the form without it? Sounds like you may need to set the permission on the server

Comment: @mplungjan : The javascript code prior to submitting does some checking and sets several variables and submits it. BTW I'm running tomcat7. Where can we set the permission on the server.

Comment: Also please do not submit when you can do `document.videoReleaseForm.onsubmit=function() { if(some kind of error)  { alert("some kind of error"); return false; } return true; }`

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this is to return true/false in javascript function and use "onsubmit" of form.

```
<form name="videoReleaseForm" id="videoReleaseForm" action="studController" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

and in "validate" javascript function, return either true or false.

true will carry the action to servlet and false will not.

I've done a similar implementation and it works.